# VB.net 2019 RDLC report sharing to the client PC

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have some question regarding VB 2019 RDLC report sharing to the client.

I am creating a setup .exe file for my application and install it locally, it works perfectly on my local PC.

Now I share the .exe to the local client PC, the client PC can access it with no issue

[image]

When I set the report reference, the client site is not able to access the report. What I have tried:

[image]

1. manually drag the .dll file to the .exe file location, but no work
2. manually add the .dll assembly file while creating the setup, but no work

[image]

3. remove the report reference, it works, but I want to use the report reference in order to generate barcode

Can I know any way to solve this problem or any way to know which file is needed to install in client side while I deploying the report with my application?

Answer (score 0):

In my project i sent the barcode image from my code inside the list, table, etc. Along with all data

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if without using the report, how u going to print it out

Comment: all I need is how to let the client pc able to detect the host RDLC's reference assembly. it is work perfect at my local